# Как добраться к дочернему элементу?

Tags: javascript, html

HTML:

```
<div class="basket_price_block">                
    <img src="images/personal_cabinet/basket1.png" class="basket_price_image" alt="" />
    <div class="basket_price">
        <span class="product_price" data-unitprice="4500">4500</span>
        <span>USD</span>                        
    </div>
    <div class="selected_basket_product">                    
        <span class="basket_minus_unregistered"> - </span>
        <input class="basket_number_unregistered" name="basket_number" value="1" />
        <span class="basket_plus_unregistered"> + </span>                                        
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>                               
</div>
```

Как по клику на любой `child` блока `selected_baset_product` добраться к первому `span`-у из блока `basket_price`?
Допустим, я кликаю на `-` (то есть это `target`), далее `selected_basket_product` - это `parentNode`, а что дальше?

Comment: `childNodes`? https://learn.javascript.ru/traversing-dom

Comment: Так сработает: `$(this).parent().siblings('.basket_price').find('span.product_price');`?

Comment: мне бы на js. Но используя childNodes то `img` ' это childNodes[1]  `basket_price` , а если выбирать через [2] тогда в кончоле пишет #text

Comment: @dirk использование jQuery - это тоже "на JS", потому что библиотека jQuery написана на JS. Корректнее говорить "мне бы без jQuery".

Answer (score 3):

Если

```
<span class="basket_minus_unregistered" onclick="getToPrice(this);"> - </span>
```

то

```
function getToPrice(el) {
    console.log(el.parentNode.previousElementSibling.children[0]);
}
```

Даст Вам

```
<span class="product_price" data-unitprice="4500">4500</span>
```

Подойдет?

Comment: помогло, спасибо! но по ходу возник вопрос , если выбирать через `childNodes` то почему `childNodes[1]` это `img` а `basket_price` это `childNodes[3]

Comment: не уверен. Может быть у Вас там пробел или еще как "невидимый" знак, который DOM видит?

Comment: Если мой ответ Вас устроил, пожалуйста, галочку нажмите, чтобы пометить как отвеченный. "Не корысти ради", а токмо для повышения кол-ва отвеченных вопросов в сообществе :) Спасибо

Comment: @dirk используйте `.children` вместо `.childNodes`, если вам не нужно учитывать текст и комментарии.

Comment: @Regent. Спасибо. Ответ исправлен